# How to conditionally move files from one directory to another?

Tags: python, file, move, shutil, errno

I'm trying to conditionally move some files from one directory to another using Shutil.

Here's my code:

```py
files = [
 '152_rand_6762_1540.npz',
 '14_rand_7652_-2532.npz',
 '1079_rand_1947_-484.npz',
 '152_rand_6209_1217.npz',
 '928_rand_3784_-934.npz',
 '984_rand_3992_-10.npz',
 '1245_rand_3214_-91.npz']

test_samples = [984, 152, 409, 1245, 12, 1336]

source = 'D:/task/rand/' 
dest = 'D:/task/xtra_rand/'

def move_subset(source):
    files = os.listdir(source)
    count = 0
    for file in files:
        pathz = os.path.join(source, file)
        for num in test_samples:
            if str(num) == file.split('_')[0]:
                if not os.path.exists(dest+file):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(source,file),os.path.join(dest, file))
                    print(num , 'found')
                    count += 1
                else:
                    os.remove(dest+file)
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(source,file),os.path.join(dest, file))
                    count += 1       
            print('moved: ', count)

move_subset(source)
```

It runs for a while then gives this error message:

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/task/rand/152_rand_1355_512.npz
> ```

The file being moved at the time of failure is also lost as it's neither in  `source` nor `dest` directories.

Does anyone know how to resolve this or any other methods of conditionally moving files?

Comment: From looking at this, it looks to me that in your "else" area you're trying to remove the file by combining dest+file, which might be throwing the error. What happens if you do os.remove(os.path.join(dest,file)) ?

Comment: @RyanBarnes Thanks for the response but I'm still getting the same errors unfortunately.

Comment: I tried your code, changed a little thing so it would adapt to my pc, and it seems to work fine. Would you like to see what worked, or do you think it surly wouldn't help?

Comment: please, provide the full error message, including the source line that gives that message

Comment: Has the code run before? I ask because you are using the move command, which means the file is no longer in the original destination. If that’s the case, it would make sense that the remove command returns an error. If it hasn’t worked, have you ensured the file path and name are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses guys. I'm still not sure what was causing the issue with my code, but I came up the code below which seems to be more robust. Posting for anyone who encounters the same issue.

```
def move_subset(source):
    files = os.listdir(source)
    count = 0
    for file in files:
        num = int(file.split('_')[0])
        if num in test_samples:
            target = os.path.join(dest, file)
            if os.path.exists(target):
                os.remove(target)
            shutil.move(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))
            print('%s found' % num)
            count += 1
        print('moved: %d' % count)

move_subset(source)
```